# Magit: amend the last commit with sign off

Tags: magit

What if I forget to sign-off my last commit, how can I fix the last commit within Magit?

I can do that with git command:

```
$ git commit --signoff --amend
```

Of cause I can write the sign-off by hand in the rebase reword buffer, but does Magit provide easy way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Changing the last commit message

What you are wanting to do is change (rewrite) the last commit message to add the signed-off line.

Go to the git status window (a common key binding is `C-x g`)

type `c` to get into commit

type `-s` to enable the signed-off line

type `w` to reword the last commit message, check that you have the wanted signed-off field.

type `C-cC-c` to do the commit

## To enable `-s` as the default

You can set the `-s` option as the default by

type `c` to go to commit

If needed, type `C-t` to enable the common options

type `-s` to toggle the signed-off, toggle other options as desired.

type `C-cC-c` to set the defaults.

Comment: I somehow didn't realize that amending is `commit` command.  It's exactly what I type in the command line.   git **c**ommit --**s**ignoff --**a**mend.  It's just that magit is better than git, and using re**w**ord, which translates to `--amend --only`.

Comment: `C-t` isn't bound to anything when using magit. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: @RickyRobinson  `C-t` is bound to `transient-show` for me. I see from other answers that magit has advanced in the last 4 years, and I don't seem to need the `C-t` currently.